# Get char from multi-string array

Tags: java

I have a string array which looks like:

```
String[] rows = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
```

How can I get a specific index of a certain row?
If I do `rows[6]` i get an out of bounds ex.
However when I do `rows[2]` i get the entire `CCC` string.

Do I have to get the row first, then get a specific char? Or can I not just grab it from the array?

Comment: What did you expect `rows[6]` to return? You've got an array of strings - so when you access that array by index, you do indeed get the whole string - and then you can get the character within that string using `charAt`.

Comment: I expected it to return `B`. But seeing as its an array, that was silly to think it would return a single letter...

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Java has 0-indexed arrays, like most programming languages. Even if the array worked as you expected it to, it would have returned 'C'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get the character at the desired index after retrieving the string element, e.g.:

```
String[] rows = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
System.out.println(rows[2].charAt(2));   // C
```

If you want to (and if you really have to), you can concatenate all elements using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) so that the result is `AAABBBCCC`, and use [`StringBuilder#charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#charAt(int)):

```
String[] rows = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String row : rows) {
    sb.append(row);
}
System.out.println(sb.charAt(6));  // C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] rows = {"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
```

is a way of initializing your array with 3 elements at index 0,1 and 2(length 3). So you have to get your String first and you can use chatAt(position).

Answer (score 0):

```
rows[1].charAt(2) // B
rows[0].charAt(0) // A
```